no matching function for call to ‘llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef::ExecutorSymbolDef(llvm::JITEvaluatedSymbol&)
I'm trying to build a tool. It has support for LLVM 15.0.7. But when I'm trying to build it using LLVM 19, I get the following error. I want to pinpoint and understand why the error occurred and on exactly which file should I do modification to build the tool error free.
The log:
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/LLJIT.h:476:27: note: remove ‘std::move’ call
In file included from /home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/DenseSet.h:17,
                 from /home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Function.h:20,
                 from /home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Module.h:25,
                 from /home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h:24,
                 from /home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/MCJIT.h:17,
                 from /home/pegasus/Documents/bpftime/vm/llvm-jit/src/llvm/llvm_jit_context.cpp:17:
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/DenseMap.h: In instantiation of ‘BucketT* llvm::DenseMapBase<DerivedT, KeyT, ValueT, KeyInfoT, BucketT>::InsertIntoBucket(BucketT*, KeyArg&&, ValueArgs&& ...) [with KeyArg = const llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr&; ValueArgs = {llvm::JITEvaluatedSymbol&}; DerivedT = llvm::DenseMap<llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr, llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef>; KeyT = llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr; ValueT = llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef; KeyInfoT = llvm::DenseMapInfo<llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr>; BucketT = llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr, llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef>]’:
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/DenseMap.h:271:33:   required from ‘std::pair<llvm::DenseMapIterator<KeyT, ValueT, KeyInfoT, BucketT>, bool> llvm::DenseMapBase<DerivedT, KeyT, ValueT, KeyInfoT, BucketT>::try_emplace(const KeyT&, Ts&& ...) [with Ts = {llvm::JITEvaluatedSymbol&}; DerivedT = llvm::DenseMap<llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr, llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef>; KeyT = llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr; ValueT = llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef; KeyInfoT = llvm::DenseMapInfo<llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr>; BucketT = llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr, llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef>]’
/home/pegasus/Documents/bpftime/vm/llvm-jit/src/llvm/llvm_jit_context.cpp:319:26:   required from here
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/DenseMap.h:577:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef::ExecutorSymbolDef(llvm::JITEvaluatedSymbol&)’
  577 |     ::new (&TheBucket->getSecond()) ValueT(std::forward<ValueArgs>(Values)...);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/TargetProcessControlTypes.h:22,
                 from /home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/ExecutorProcessControl.h:19,
                 from /home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Core.h:22:
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:27:3: note: candidate: ‘llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef::ExecutorSymbolDef(llvm::orc::ExecutorAddr, llvm::JITSymbolFlags)’
   27 |   ExecutorSymbolDef(ExecutorAddr Addr, JITSymbolFlags Flags)
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:27:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:26:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef::ExecutorSymbolDef()’
   26 |   ExecutorSymbolDef() = default;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:26:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:24:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef::ExecutorSymbolDef(const llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef&)’
   24 | class ExecutorSymbolDef {
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:24:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘llvm::JITEvaluatedSymbol’ to ‘const llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef&’
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:24:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef::ExecutorSymbolDef(llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef&&)’
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:24:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘llvm::JITEvaluatedSymbol’ to ‘llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef&&’
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/DenseMap.h: In instantiation of ‘BucketT* llvm::DenseMapBase<DerivedT, KeyT, ValueT, KeyInfoT, BucketT>::InsertIntoBucket(BucketT*, KeyArg&&, ValueArgs&& ...) [with KeyArg = llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr; ValueArgs = {llvm::JITEvaluatedSymbol&}; DerivedT = llvm::DenseMap<llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr, llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef>; KeyT = llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr; ValueT = llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef; KeyInfoT = llvm::DenseMapInfo<llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr>; BucketT = llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr, llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef>]’:
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/DenseMap.h:247:25:   required from ‘std::pair<llvm::DenseMapIterator<KeyT, ValueT, KeyInfoT, BucketT>, bool> llvm::DenseMapBase<DerivedT, KeyT, ValueT, KeyInfoT, BucketT>::try_emplace(KeyT&&, Ts&& ...) [with Ts = {llvm::JITEvaluatedSymbol&}; DerivedT = llvm::DenseMap<llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr, llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef>; KeyT = llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr; ValueT = llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef; KeyInfoT = llvm::DenseMapInfo<llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr>; BucketT = llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<llvm::orc::SymbolStringPtr, llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef>]’
/home/pegasus/Documents/bpftime/vm/llvm-jit/src/llvm/llvm_jit_context.cpp:340:24:   required from here
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/DenseMap.h:577:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef::ExecutorSymbolDef(llvm::JITEvaluatedSymbol&)’
  577 |     ::new (&TheBucket->getSecond()) ValueT(std::forward<ValueArgs>(Values)...);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:27:3: note: candidate: ‘llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef::ExecutorSymbolDef(llvm::orc::ExecutorAddr, llvm::JITSymbolFlags)’
   27 |   ExecutorSymbolDef(ExecutorAddr Addr, JITSymbolFlags Flags)
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:27:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:26:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef::ExecutorSymbolDef()’
   26 |   ExecutorSymbolDef() = default;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:26:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:24:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef::ExecutorSymbolDef(const llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef&)’
   24 | class ExecutorSymbolDef {
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:24:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘llvm::JITEvaluatedSymbol’ to ‘const llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef&’
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:24:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef::ExecutorSymbolDef(llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef&&)’
/home/pegasus/Documents/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/Shared/ExecutorSymbolDef.h:24:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘llvm::JITEvaluatedSymbol’ to ‘llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef&&’
/usr/bin/cmake: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
[ 80%] Linking CXX executable bpftime_frida_uprobe_attach_tests
/usr/bin/cmake: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
/usr/bin/cmake: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
[ 80%] Linking CXX executable bpftime_syscall_trace_attach_tests
/usr/bin/cmake: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pegasus/Documents/bpftime/build'
/usr/bin/cmake: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
[ 80%] Built target bpftime_syscall_trace_attach_tests
gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pegasus/Documents/bpftime/build'
/usr/bin/cmake: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
[ 80%] Built target bpftime_frida_uprobe_attach_tests
/usr/bin/cmake: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
[ 80%] Linking CXX executable bpftime
/usr/bin/cmake: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
gmake[3]: *** [vm/llvm-jit/CMakeFiles/vm-bpf.dir/build.make:90: vm/llvm-jit/CMakeFiles/vm-bpf.dir/src/llvm/llvm_jit_context.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pegasus/Documents/bpftime/build'
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:852: vm/llvm-jit/CMakeFiles/vm-bpf.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/bin/ld: warning: generated-config_archs_linux-x86_64_asm_crypto_whrlpool_wp-x86_64.s.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
/usr/bin/ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker
gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pegasus/Documents/bpftime/build'
/usr/bin/cmake: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
[ 80%] Built target bpftime-cli-cpp
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pegasus/Documents/bpftime/build'
gmake[1]: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pegasus/Documents/bpftime/build'
make: *** [Makefile:62: release] Error 2

The 319 line of llvm_jit_context is
    // Create a JIT builder
    SPDLOG_DEBUG("LLVM-JIT: Creating LLJIT instance");
    auto jit = ExitOnErr(LLJITBuilder().create());

    auto &mainDylib = jit->getMainJITDylib();
    std::vector<std::string> extFuncNames;
    // insert the helper functions
    SymbolMap extSymbols;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < std::size(vm->ext_funcs); i++) {
        if (vm->ext_funcs[i] != nullptr) {
            auto sym = JITEvaluatedSymbol::fromPointer(
                vm->ext_funcs[i]);
            auto symName = jit->getExecutionSession().intern(
                ext_func_sym(i));
            sym.setFlags(JITSymbolFlags::Callable |
                     JITSymbolFlags::Exported);
        --->    extSymbols.try_emplace(symName, sym);
            extFuncNames.push_back(ext_func_sym(i));
        }
    }

The 577 no line of Densemap.h is
  template <typename KeyArg, typename... ValueArgs>
  BucketT *InsertIntoBucket(BucketT *TheBucket, KeyArg &&Key,
                            ValueArgs &&... Values) {
    TheBucket = InsertIntoBucketImpl(Key, Key, TheBucket);

    TheBucket->getFirst() = std::forward<KeyArg>(Key);
   ---> ::new (&TheBucket->getSecond()) ValueT(std::forward<ValueArgs>(Values)...);
    return TheBucket;
  }


We need a [mcve]

It is reasonable to assume that enough changed between four major releases of such huge project as llvm, that a dependent project cannot just be built with with an unreleased version 19 when it only supports up to version 15. If you cloned the llvm git, you could go back to a tagged commit that is compatible with the tool you are trying to build.

Since LLVM 17. The function signature has changed.
auto sym = JITEvaluatedSymbol::fromPointer(
                vm->ext_funcs[i]->fn);

It was the cause of the error.
After replacing this with
auto symbol = ::llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef (::llvm::orc::ExecutorAddr (sym.getAddress()), sym.getFlags());

solved the issue
extSymbols.try_emplace(symName, symbol);

rather than extSymbols.try_emplace(symName, symb);
The updated total code:
    std::vector<std::string> extFuncNames;
    // insert the helper functions
    SymbolMap extSymbols;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < std::size(vm->ext_funcs); i++) {
        if (vm->ext_funcs[i].has_value()) {
            auto sym = JITEvaluatedSymbol::fromPointer(
                vm->ext_funcs[i]->fn);
            auto symName = jit->getExecutionSession().intern(
                ext_func_sym(i));
            sym.setFlags(JITSymbolFlags::Callable |
                     JITSymbolFlags::Exported);
            

        #if LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR < 17
            extSymbols.try_emplace(symName, sym);
            extFuncNames.push_back(ext_func_sym(i));
        #else
            auto symbol = ::llvm::orc::ExecutorSymbolDef (::llvm::orc::ExecutorAddr (sym.getAddress()), sym.getFlags());
            extSymbols.try_emplace(symName, symbol);
            extFuncNames.emplace_back(ext_func_sym(i));
        #endif
            
        }
    }

